# How to disable "ThinkPad Zoom"?

Tags: windows-vista, thinkpad

I have a ThinkPad T61p that is running Vista 32-bit SP2.  I program in Eclipse a lot, and I find that when I try to type the code completion hotkey (Ctrl-Space), I often accidentally press the ThinkPad Zoom combination (Fn-Space).  This not only causes the screen to switch to 800x600 resolution, but it swaps ALL my running applications back in, and derails whatever train of thought I had.

Does anyone know a way to disable this particular Fn-key combination?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this feature is completely useless and you would like to remove it permanently, you can always go to Vista's *Control Panel > Programs and Features*, and uninstall the *Thinkpad Fullscreen Magnifier* utility.

That will disable the Fn+Space keyboard combo.

Comment: +1 Man, you're fast :). What's the time in Singapore, btw?

Comment: @alex oh darn, it's 4:37 in the morning. then again... it's FRRRIIIDDAAAAYY tomorrow!! :) go to work, hang on for the day, and then it's le weekend!

Comment: It just became Friday where I live as well :).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [this thread](http://stderr.org/pipermail/thinkpad/2006-October/023712.html) can help. Here's what they say about it:

> If you don't plan to use the feature,
>   you can use Add/Remove Programs to
>   uninstall the ThinkPad FullScreen
>   Magnifier.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do this with my Lenovo running Windows 7 Pro x64, however, I did not want to uninstall it because I may need it later or another user on the laptop may need it.

So what I did was use the utility "pskill.exe" from SysInternals (Microsoft) and terminate the program "tpscrex.exe" upon login (using a shortcut in the user's Startup programs group).